# Why is jQuery loading multiple dialogs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I click on the image. Then the dialog opens. I close the dialog and reclick the image to open it. The I see 2 dialogs opened when I scroll down. Can anyone explain why is it happening. I want the dialog to be opened and closed only once.

jsFiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wqtfu/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var dialogOpts = {
            title: "Fullscreen",
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: jQuery(window).width(),
            height: jQuery(window).height(),
            maxwidth: jQuery(window).width(),
            maxheight: jQuery(window).height(),
            closeOnEscape: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            zIndex: 99999999,
            open: function() {
               jQuery("#zoomframe").append(jQuery("<iframe />").attr({src: "www.google.com",
                                                                        frameborder: "0",
                                                                        scrolling: "no",
                                                                        width: jQuery(window).width(),
                                                                        height: jQuery(window).height()
                                                                         }));
            },
            close: function() {
                jQuery(this).hide();
            }

            };

    jQuery("#zoomframe").dialog(dialogOpts);

    jQuery("#mainimage").click(
                function (event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    jQuery("#zoomframe").dialog("open");
                    return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: you are adding another iframe to the dialog every time it opens. You don't get multiple dialogs, you get multiple iframes within the same dialog.

Comment: I didn't post as an answer because what you change will depend on what you want your code to actually do. Either add the iframe once or remove it every time the dialog closes, or change its source each time you show the dialog

Comment: What @MrOBrian said is correct.You need to remove the iframe everytime  the dialog closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code to the following as **MrOBrian** said in the comments to the question and it worked!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var dialogOpts = {
            title: "Fullscreen",
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: jQuery(window).width(),
            height: jQuery(window).height(),
            maxwidth: jQuery(window).width(),
            maxheight: jQuery(window).height(),
            closeOnEscape: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            zIndex: 99999999,
            open: function() {
               jQuery("#zoomframe").append(jQuery("<iframe />").attr({src:    "www.google.com",
                                                                        id: "myzoomframe",
                                                                        frameborder: "0",
                                                                        scrolling: "no",
                                                                        width: jQuery(window).width(),
                                                                        height: jQuery(window).height()
                                                                         }));
            },
            close: function() {
                jQuery(this).hide();
                jQuery('#myzoomframe').remove();
            }

            };

    jQuery("#zoomframe").dialog(dialogOpts);

    jQuery("#mainimage").click(
                function (event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    jQuery("#zoomframe").dialog("open");
                    return false;
    });

});
```